# For $a\in \mathbb{R}$: Does $a^n \rightarrow 0$ when $|a| < 1$ imply that $a^n$ is unbounded when $|a| > 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

On pages 50-51 in the book *Introduction to Analysis* by Rosenlicht, the author claims the following (see yellow highlight):

---

[image]

---

How does this *readily* follow as a consequence of the example?

I don't think the example is sufficient to conclude that $a^n$ grows without bound when $|a| > 1$, there's a detail missing.

For example we need to use some form of Archimedean property to show that for a given real $M$ there exists an integer $m \geq 1$ such that $a^m > M$). Or use properties of exponentials by writing $|a|^n = e^{ n \cdot \ln |a|  }$, whose behaviour we are familiar with.

And such a detail makes no reference to the fact that $a^n \rightarrow 0$ when $|a| < 1$. So how exactly is the unbounded case a consequence of the bounded case? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Consider the multiplicative inverses of real numbers larger than 1

Comment: Please replace the image of text by actual text to make the question accessible to people with screen readers etc.

Comment: Sorry about it, will definitely think about it next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|a|  > 1$, then $|1/a| = 1/|a| < 1$ and consequently by what is already established
$$\lim_n \frac{1}{|a|^n}= 0$$
which is equivalent with
$$\lim_n |a|^n = \infty$$

Hence, $(a^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is unbounded.

Comment: Wow it was that simple, I feel so dumb. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $|a|>1$ and that $M>0$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1a\right)^n=0$, if $n$ is large enough, $\left|\frac1{a^n}\right|<\frac1M$. But$$\left|\frac1{a^n}\right|<\frac1M\iff|a^n|>M.$$This proves that $(a^n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is unbounded.